# Configure mod_rest module for the ejabberd server

Tags: rest, erlang, xmpp, ejabberd

I am in the process of configuring the ejabber server for one of our project.In this we need to configure the mod_rest module (https://github.com/processone/ejabberd-contrib) from ejabberd-contrib. Below are my configuration (YAML)
in listen

```
 port: 5280
    module: ejabberd_http
    request_handlers:
      "/rest": mod_rest
    web_admin: true
    http_poll: true
    http_bind: true
    ## register: true
    captcha: true


modules:
  mod_rest:
    allowed_ips:
      - "host_one_ip"
      - "host_one_ip"
    access_commands:
      - "registered_users"
      - "connected_users"
    allowed_destinations:
      - "all"
```

But whenever i am trying to hit the ejabberd command using the rest (curl call)  its giving me "TryPOSTING Stanza"

```
    prompt# curl --data 'registered_users domain' -X POST http://host:5280/rest/

Try POSTing a stanza.
```

I tried to go though the forum but couldn't find ...anything helpful

I am new to ejabber and erlang. Any pointer in this direction will be very helpful. Please let me know if any more details are required.

Comment: Same problem here, unfortunately I don't know Erlang, would debug it otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guys i have figured out the issue for this. I have installed Ejabberd 14.05 version. The mod_rest module
was including the ejabberd_http.hrl file for its dev_include directories.In the Ejabberd 14.05 the record for ejabberd_http.hrl are changed. "opts = [] :: list()," is an extra header in the ejabber-contrib`s include folder. I adjusted the header location accordingly and compile the module. It worked for me :) with this i got the ejabberd commands working using the mod_rest. 
Now my i facing problem to consumes Stanzas using mod_rest :(. If anyone have any thoughts on the same please let me know.

Comment: Can you share your code/changes? Here would be a good place: https://github.com/processone/ejabberd-contrib/issues/45

A gist or something else would be fine too.

Comment: Hey Chris i added my comment there, there is actually no code change just we need to point to proper file :). But now i am facing   new issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27442324/presence-stanze-for-ejabberd-now-working-via-mod-rest-module

Comment: Hey, I've seen it, very nice, thank you! I will try it out soon. Unfortunately I have no idea regarding your stanza problem, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I try this, and worked:

In my case I use ejabberd binary installation, and the installation folder in
/lib/ejabberd/xxxx

Compile the mod_rest.erl from ejabberd-contrib, here is the reference, https://www.ejabberd.im/ejabberd-contrib

I compiled using this command :

```
erlc -I /lib/ejabberd/include your_mod_rest_source_file
```

if success, you will have .beam file, after that copy the mod_rest.beam to ejabberd installation folder

```
cp ~/ejabberd-contrib/mod_rest/src/mod_rest.beam /lib/ejabberd/ebin/
```

than configure ejabberd.yml in my case the yml reside in (/etc/ejabberd/ejabberd.yml) like this:

https://github.com/processone/ejabberd-contrib/issues/45#issuecomment-69767670

Answer (score -1):

I think you misunderstand the purpose of the ReST module.
From the doc, you are supposed to send XMPP stanza to it:
https://github.com/processone/ejabberd-contrib/tree/master/mod_rest

However, you are sending plain text, not XMPP stanza (not even XML).

Comment: Hey Michael, Thanks for the reply but, what i am trying is that i need to get the ejabber command working using the mod_rest module.In the Readme given they have mentioned it how it should work.

Comment: EXAMPLE AUTH COMMAND WITH WGET
 ==============================

To execute an ejabberd command, simply provide its name and arguments as in ejabberdctl:
wget http://localhost:5280/rest/ --server-response --post-data 'registered_users localhost'

If you configure access_commands option, you must provide the credentials like this:
 wget http://localhost:5280/rest/ --server-response --post-data '--auth user1 localhost thepass registered_users localhost'

Comment: I do not think it works by just passing the ejabberdctl command to rest API. You have to pass them as ReST parameters.

Comment: POSTing a Stanza doesn't work either. POSTing the ejabberdctl command to mod_rest should work, too.

Comment: can you please let me know the parameter name, as in the readme file at github they have not mentioned it :(