# Presence Stanze for ejabberd NOT working via mod_rest module

Tags: rest, erlang, xmpp, ejabberd

Currently i am using ejabberd 14.05 server and using it`s mod_rest module to update the presence of the user  from server based on a certain condition from a 3rd party web service. But i am not able to post the presence stanza to update the presence of user. Below are my finding.

command using to invoke the presence stanza via mod_rest.
    curl --verbose --data "World"  -X POST servername:5280/rest/ -H "Content-Type: text/xml" -H "Accept: application/xml"

logs.

```
==> error.log <==
```

2014-12-12 03:00:20.055 [error] <0.1199.0> CRASH REPORT Process <0.1199.0> with 0 neighbours crashed with reason: no function clause matching xml:get_tag_attr_s(<<"from">>, {error,{4,<<"not well-formed (invalid token)">>}}) line 362

```
==> ejabberd.log <==
2014-12-12 03:00:20.049 [info] <0.557.0>@ejabberd_listener:accept:313 (#Port<0.6318>) Accepted connection 127.0.0.1:51838 -> 127.0.0.1:5280
2014-12-12 03:00:20.049 [debug] <0.1199.0>@ejabberd_http:init:145 S: [{[<<"rest">>],mod_rest},{[<<"captcha">>],ejabberd_captcha},{[<<"admin">>],ejabberd_web_admin},{[<<"http-bind">>],mod_http_bind},{[<<"http-poll">>],ejabberd_http_poll}]
2014-12-12 03:00:20.049 [info] <0.1199.0>@ejabberd_http:init:149 started: {gen_tcp,#Port<0.6318>}
2014-12-12 03:00:20.050 [debug] <0.1199.0>@ejabberd_http:process_header:277 (#Port<0.6318>) http query: 'POST' /rest/
2014-12-12 03:00:20.050 [debug] <0.1199.0>@ejabberd_http:process_request:438 client data: <<"<message to=user@test.com from=localhost/rest><body>World</body></message>">>
2014-12-12 03:00:20.050 [debug] <0.1199.0>@ejabberd_http:process:350 [<<"rest">>] matches [<<"rest">>]
2014-12-12 03:00:20.050 [debug] <0.1199.0>@ejabberd_http:process:354 [{'Content-Length',<<"108">>},{'Accept',<<"application/xml">>},{'Content-Type',<<"text/xml">>},{'Host',<<"servername:5280">>},{'User-Agent',<<"curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.15.3 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2">>}]
2014-12-12 03:00:20.050 [info] <0.1199.0>@mod_rest:maybe_post_request:70 Stanza: {error,{4,<<"not well-formed (invalid token)">>}}
2014-12-12 03:00:20.055 [error] <0.1199.0> CRASH REPORT Process <0.1199.0> with 0 neighbours crashed with reason: no function clause matching xml:get_tag_attr_s(<<"from">>, {error,{4,<<"not well-formed (invalid token)">>}}) line 362

==> error.log <==
2014-12-12 03:00:20.055 [error] <0.311.0> Supervisor ejabberd_http_sup had child undefined started with {ejabberd_http,start_link,undefined} at <0.1199.0> exit with reason function_clause in context child_terminated

==> ejabberd.log <==
2014-12-12 03:00:20.055 [error] <0.311.0> Supervisor ejabberd_http_sup had child undefined started with {ejabberd_http,start_link,undefined} at <0.1199.0> exit with reason function_clause in context child_terminated
```

Its somehow not able to parse the stanza. Not sure why this is happening :( Any pointers in this direction are useful. 
Please also let me know there is any another approach to do this would be also helpful.

EDIT 1: There was some issue with the CURL. So i switched to POSTMan Client in chrome.Now the stanza are atleast getting parsed. Now the issue is that the message stanza is working for me but the Presence  stanza is not working for me. I am now able to establish the client to server session.Can any one please help me with  it.

**Code for set_presence method in mod_admin_extra.erl**

**Command definition**

```
#ejabberd_commands{name = set_presence,
                    tags = [session],
                    desc = "Set presence of a session",
                    module = ?MODULE, function = set_presence,
                    args = [{user, string}, {host, string},
                            {resource, string}, {type, string},
                            {show, string}, {status, string},
                            {priority, string}],
                    result = {res, rescode}},
```

**Command Body** As of now i have commented most of the body. Once i get the valid Pid, i will uncomment the rest of the code.

```
set_presence(User, Host, Resource, Type, Show, Status, Priority) ->
    Pid = ejabberd_sm:get_session_pid(User, Host, Resource),
%%    USR = User ++ "@" ++ Host ++ "/" ++ Resource,
%%    US = User ++ "@" ++ Host,
%%    Message = {route_xmlstreamelement,
%%             {xmlel, <<"presence">>,
%%              [{<<"from">>, USR}, {<<"to">>, US}, {<<"type">>, Type}],
%%              [{xmlel, <<"show">>, [], [{xmlcdata, Show}]},
%%               {xmlel, <<"status">>, [], [{xmlcdata, Status}]},
%%               {xmlel, <<"priority">>, [], [{xmlcdata, Priority}]}]}},

%%    ?INFO_MSG("Message : ~p~n",[Message]),
    ?INFO_MSG("Pid : ~s~n",[Pid]).
%%    Pid ! Message.
```

**Usage**

```
su - root set_presence 2067343756 host 5599628551424712277712378 subscribed dnd Im_away_25_minutes 127
```

**Output**

```
Problem 'error undef' occurred executing the command.
Stacktrace: [{p1_logger,info_msg,[mod_admin_extra,926,"Pid : ~s~n",[none]],[]},
             {ejabberd_ctl,call_command,3,
                           [{file,"src/ejabberd_ctl.erl"},{line,293}]},
             {ejabberd_ctl,try_call_command,3,
                           [{file,"src/ejabberd_ctl.erl"},{line,269}]},
             {ejabberd_ctl,process2,3,
                           [{file,"src/ejabberd_ctl.erl"},{line,218}]},
             {ejabberd_ctl,process,1,
                           [{file,"src/ejabberd_ctl.erl"},{line,203}]},
             {rpc,'-handle_call_call/6-fun-0-',5,
                  [{file,"rpc.erl"},{line,205}]}]
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why you would need to send a presence stanza.

Sending just a presence stanza is not enough to simulate user presence. There will still not be any XMPP sessions associated with that presence stanza.

And yes, you were sending incorrect XML data on the socket previously.

Comment: Hey Michael,thanks a lot for reply.Yes, you are right just sending the presence stanza is not working for me there has to be a session associated with it. My Requirement is that i need to update the presence of a user on a particular condition like if he receives a phone call on his hard phone, then i need to update his presence as busy. So i am trying to use mod_rest module to update his presence of user. Please let me know your thoughts on the same. I am trying to do this from couple of week and not able to figure out how to do it. Any help or pointers in this direction would be helpful.

Comment: Can you please let me know how  to establish session between client and server ?

Comment: Session is opened by connecting a real XMPP client to the server.

Comment: Ya that true, but is there any way to mock this behavior. Or can you please suggest any other way to achieve what i discussed above ??

Comment: There is no way to mock this behaviour easily. This would be a major patch / change in how ejabberd works.

Comment: Hi Mickael, i came across mod_admin_extra (https://github.com/processone/ejabberd-contrib/blob/53ca8bafba45dda146d5f909edfa6425a54f9ada/mod_admin_extra/src/mod_admin_extra.erl) on ejabberd-contrib project. In this module there is set_presence command which i assume is for setting the presence of user. I was trying to get it working but for some reason i am not able to get the Process Id (Pid) for the logged in user with his server resourceId.

Comment: Well, you can set_presence for a user that has a session open. It does not allow faking the behaviour. For what you want to do, there is a need for non trivial custom developments.

Comment: Thanks, But even if set_presence command get working that would be helpful for. What i actually want is, i need some mechanism to update the presence of a logged in user. Use case is when a user receive a call on his hardphone and if he is logged into chat client, his status should get changed to "On Phone". As there is no communication between Hardphone and Softphone we need to write a mechanism for to update the status for the same.

Comment: You did no really explain your problem in a way that you can get help. You just said: " but for some reason i am not able to get the Process Id (Pid) for the logged in user with his server resourceId." Not enough to have someone get a clue about your issue.

Comment: My Apologies for that Mickael. The issue which i am facing is in the set presence Method set_presence(User, Host, Resource, Type, Show, Status, Priority) , there is a call to get the Pid for the user. Pid = ejabberd_sm:get_session_pid(User, Host, Resource), this method is returning me Pid as None. Due to which i am not able send the presence stance for that user. Please let me know if you need any more details.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant: It only works if the user is online / has a session open. The fact that there is no session pid means that user does not have a session opened.

Comment: Yes i am trying that command whn the user is online. Buy open session do you means that user should have a resource ID. The connected_user command is returning me 2069054650@host/28250591201426520655609108

Comment: Then you have a Pid for that user while it is online.

Comment: Yes, Ideally this should return the Pid, but  in my case its not returning. I am using the same code as mentioned in the mod_admin_extra module. Do i need to do some additional changes, I am sorry for asking so many question but i am really new to Ejabber and Erlang.

Comment: Mickael, I have edited the question. Please let me know you need more details on this.

Comment: You assume PID is a string (~s) which is not the case. And the function called return the session PID is the user is logged. If the user is logged and can received messages and if that function does not return a pid, your installation / version of ejabberd is seriously broken. I recommand then you start from a clean source install.